# Creating an app that accesses all images in user's Photos for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I haven't found any documentation on this or seen this done before, but is there anyway I can, instead of just choosing one image with UIImagePicker, load the user's albums, and then after selecting an image, that image displays, but also allows me to scroll left and ride to see all the images before and after that image?

I know I can use a multiple image picker, but that involves importing all the user's photos, and if the user has hundreds of photos, this would take a lot of time. I'm looking for similar functionality to the real photos app- the performance and everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Look at the documentation for `ALAssetsLibrary`. This will allow you to enumerate all the user's image (and video) libraries. From this, you get `ALAsset`s, which you can ask for their default `ALAssetRepresentation`. This one, in turn, you ask for its `CGImage`, from which you can create a `UIImage`.

Enumerating Libraries and Assets is done in blocks, which can easily be done in the background.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I would have to import and process each photo then, a slow process?

Comment: Yes and no. You can enumerate everything without getting any image at all, which is pretty fast. Once you need to display, you can ask the `ALAsset` for a thumbnailImage. This is cached, and still relatively fast. You can do all the enumeration and even asking for the thumbnail in the background, and only need to do the actual display on the main thread (because UIView is not thread safe). Just make sure to display the view and _then_ start displaying the thumbnails, one by one.

Comment: Of course, getting the fullResolutionImage is always going to be slowish, there is no way around it. The idea is that you don't import the full library, but instead display the library to the user in your own way, and only import the parts that you need based on the user's choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the assets library: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> An instance of ALAssetsLibrary provides access to the videos and
>   photos that are under the control of the Photos application.
>
> The library includes those that are in the Saved Photos album, those
>   coming from iTunes, and those that were directly imported into the
>   device. You use it to retrieve the list of all asset groups and to
>   save images and videos into the Saved Photos album.

*note: only available in ios 4+*

Comment: But if say I have 400+ images on my album, then I would have to import and save each image?